# Check function call arguments explicitly with `verify` or implicitly with `when`?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

What is the best way to check that right argument comes to right place with `Mockito`?

Consider next unit-test:

```
@Test
public void getProjectByIdTest() {
    Long projectId = 1L;
    ProjectEntity expectedProject = mock(ProjectEntity.class);
    when(projectRepository.findOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(expectedProject);

    assertThat(projectService.getById(projectId), is(expectedProject));
    verify(projectRepository).findOne(projectId);
}
```

Here we check that `projectService` passes it's argument to the right place with `verify`, explicitly.

Now check this unit-test:

```
@Test
public void getProjectByIdTest() {
    Long projectId = 1L;
    ProjectEntity expectedProject = mock(ProjectEntity.class);
    when(projectRepository.findOne(projectId)).thenReturn(expectedProject);

    assertThat(projectService.getById(projectId), is(expectedProject));
}
```

It also checks that `projectService` passed its argument to right place, but implicitly, with `when` (so if `projectService` will actually pass some random number to `projectRepository.findOne()`, `assertThat` will fail because mock will return wrong value).

So how this should be done? It seems to me that without that `verify` this test looses some clarity; but from the other hand its shorter.

Answer (score 1):

*What are you trying to test?* You should be trying to test that your test unit (here, your test method) *works*, and only verify interactions that are important to that general contract.

```
@Test
public void getProjectByIdTest_withVerify() {
    Long projectId = 1L;
    ProjectEntity expectedProject = mock(ProjectEntity.class);

    // Your simulated dependency returns expectedProject for every ID?
    when(projectRepository.findOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(expectedProject);

    assertThat(projectService.getById(projectId), is(expectedProject));

    // Is it a requirement of your test that this method must be called?
    // Maybe your system someday calls a "findAll" method, or caches values.
    verify(projectRepository).findOne(projectId);
}
```

Compare:

```
@Test
public void getProjectByIdTest() {
    Long projectId = 1L;
    ProjectEntity expectedProject = mock(ProjectEntity.class);

    // You return the expectedProject when asked for. Everything else returns null.
    when(projectRepository.findOne(projectId)).thenReturn(expectedProject);

    // You check that the return value is correct, which implies the call succeeded.    
    assertThat(projectService.getById(projectId), is(expectedProject));
}
```

`verify` interactions definitely have their place, particularly for ArgumentCaptors and for interactions where a particular method call is part of the contract, such as a server or RPC call or void method call.

For a literally-authoritative view, read the article ["Is there a difference between asking and telling?"](https://monkeyisland.pl/2008/04/26/asking-and-telling/) by Szczepan Faber, originator of Mockito. It gives a lot of detail and insight about what can be inferred from expectations versus what is worth verification.

Comment: `Is it a requirement of your test that this method must be called? Maybe your system someday calls a "findAll" method, or caches values`. Well, if my implementation will change, both test methods will have to change too. I guess that I am testing myself and my own implementation, since I want to test my class in isolation and can't see another way to do it. If I have real database (integration tests), I would be able to just test that `projectService.getById(id)` returns expected object that I've put to database myself (and I can switch to `findAll` instead of `findOne` without test change).

Comment: Great article, shame on me I didn't find it myself! `If I stub then it is verified for free, so I don’t verify. If I verify then I don’t care about the return value, so I don’t stub`. I guess it's similar to what @davidxxx said in his answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Bear in mind that it's ideal for a test to not need to change when the implementation changes. Though Mockito interferes with that by maybe needing additional stubs, you can still write your test based on the contract instead of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Little remark. Your mockito behavior recordings are not symmetric between your two examples :

```
when(projectRepository.findOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(expectedProject);
```

and

```
when(projectRepository.findOne(projectId)).thenReturn(expectedProject);
```

You should use `when(projectRepository.findOne(projectId))` in both cases seeing how you do your assertions.

> So how this should be done? It seems to me that without that verify
>   this test looses some clarity; but from the other hand its shorter.

Personally, I consider the `verify()` as a degraded solution when the method I want to mock has no returned type.
In some cases, it allows at least to check that the dependency is called and with the expected parameters it it has.

If the method of the mocked dependency returns something, as it is in your case, the second solution seems much more natural from a unit test point of view.

When you write something like that :

```
when(projectRepository.findOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(expectedProject);
assertThat(projectService.getById(projectId), is(expectedProject));
verify(projectRepository).findOne(projectId);
```

you give the impression that you want mock the dependency repository but you want also check each called method on the repository.

First it is redundant since if 
this assertion is true :`assertThat(projectService.getById(projectId), is(expectedProject));`, it means that the repository was called with the expected argument and has returned the expected project. Why check it again with  `verify(projectRepository).findOne(projectId);`?

Secondly, the goal of a unit test is not checking that each method on a dependency was called. It doesn't bring many things in terms of assertion and you couple strongly the unit test to the api of the dependency and you make you test more complex.

Comment: Thanks, I like your reasoning! I coded that unsymmetrical behavior on purpose, to point out that we do not specify argument in first case and do verifying later in code. So you should pass expected values to when wherever you can? And about second paragraph: so If I can design dependencies of this service in a way that their methods return some values instead of just mutating arguments (e.g. ProjectEntity transform(`ProjectEntity entity) {...}` instead of `void transform(ProjectEntity entity) {...}`), I should do that to improve tests design?

Comment: You are welcome :) Thank you too.  For your first question : in your case you should pass expected values because it asserts that the mock was called with the expected argument. Mocking with any and at the end doing the verify finally performs the same assertions but it is much more verbose and as said you couple your test to the dependency. Suppose you add a parameter in the mocked method, you have to change twice in your test method to be confirm with the new dependency contract. It is not a suitable solution.

Comment: For your second question, I think that I should have not used the "degraded solution" expression. It may be misinterpreted. 
When I refer to "degraded solution" I mean that if for a method on a dependency it makes no sense to return something, the only one thing that I can check is that it is called as expected.
"I can design dependencies of this service in a way that their methods return some values instead of just mutating arguments" If it makes sense for the API of the service, yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: In your method example, it is hard to give an answer without the using context. In a general way, I would say it makes sense to return an `ProjectEntity`  in `transform(ProjectEntity projectEntity)` if `ProjectEntity` is immutable or if you want to have a fluent API.

Comment: when you rely on `when` to return something only  when the given parameters are met and your test fails then you get a `NPE` somewhere in your production code instead of a test error message that tells clearly what was expected and what was given. You will have to do some debugging to find out that it is because the parameters passed to the mocked method were wrong.

Comment: @Timothy Truckle "when you rely on when to return something only when the given parameters are met and your test fails then you get a NPE somewhere in your production code instead of a test error message that tells clearly what was expected and what was given."  **What you said has no relation with what the OP asks**. He asks on the way to perform the check with a mock object (`any()` or a specific value) and you here you refer to the fact of testing another scenario. Please don't make things  confuse for the OP.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I see your point, but I guess that NPE error is also useful, because its stacktrace may show you *where* exactly that `null` appeared. With `verify` Mockito will tell you that mock recieved unexpected parameter, but not where.

Comment: @davidxxx my question is about the best (most reasonable) way to do so (check argument). I am aware of ways to do so, but I am inexperienced, so I decided to ask on SO.

Comment: @RomanGolyshev *"I guess that NPE error is also useful, because its stacktrace may show you where exactly that null appeared."* The `NPE` is only a symptom,nit the root cause of the error. The actual call having the wrong parameters could be anywhere before the `NPE` occured. Also: that the `cut` fails to pass the right parameters could be due to another call on a dependency that returned `null` but was passed in to this one. All of this will force you to debug your `cut`. But I like my tests to clearly show what went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The third most important thing about UnitTest after *failing for the right reason* and being *fast* is *to be readable*.

The reader of the test should easily see why the the test is failing. So configure your mock to be as tolerant as possible and check the behavior in your *verify*.

Comment: @davidxxx Thanks for the downvote without reasoning just for revenge, that's very adult...